# Azure's CloudContext.Clients.Create????ManagementClient methods deprecated?

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

We've upgraded to latest Azure Management libraries from Nuget and are seeing that the calls to CloudContext.Clients.Create-various-management-clients no longer exist.  Is there a substituation somewhere else for this functionality?

TIA

Comment: Which version of the library are you using? I believe from one version, they simply dropped "sync" versions and replaced them with "async" versions.

Comment: Just upgraded to whatever latest Nuget had a few hours ago. I didnt see Async versions either, will check again

Comment: Sorry ... my bad ... I was actually thinking of actual operations (like listing storage accounts). From one version there was only async version of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it appeared that there is a decent amount of updates in the "Preview" mode of Nuget libraries for this.

It looks like some libraries, /at this time/ are released as stable releases that point correlate with dependencies in the "Preview" state.  So, all of the CloudContext.Client extension methods are only present in the Preview library as Microsoft is migrating namespaces from Microsoft.WindowsAzure to Microsoft.Azure

Very confusing at the moment, hopefully things will clear up

Comment: By "Preview" state, do you mean the pre-release 'WindowsAzure.Storage.4.3.2-preview' package? I was wondering what namespace was newer, thanks for mentioning it in your answer.

Comment: Yep.  By default pre-release nuget packages are not showing up in Nuget, so it is harder to find'em unless you know to look for them

Comment: looking at the net40 dll in WindowsAzure.Storage.4.3.2-preview it's namespace is Microsoft.WindowsAzure. So I still don't know what they are doing for namespaces.